# shortcut for searchbar in applications

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I use Windows 8.1 Pro and I mostly use keyboard shortcut for most instead of mouse. But I have a big problem in using keyboard for search some words in applications. I use "Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary" application and It is big issue that every time I want to search a word in dictionary I should use mouse and click on the search bar in order to being able to write the word. I tried find shortcut for it but I couldn't. Is there any way to use shortcut or create shortcut for this?[image]

Here is search bar in top left corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [AutoHotKey.](https://www.autohotkey.com/)

Install AutoHotKey, then create a file named *oxfordScript.ahk* on your desktop with the following contents:

```
^j::
Click, 113,127
return
```

- `^j` is the shortcut for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Change this to
  whatever you like.
- `Click, 113, 127` clicks at those coordinates when
  you press the shortcut. I took these from your screenshot image, so
  you may have to tweak this to click the search bar correctly.
- `return` ends your shortcut file.

Right click on the file you created, open it with AutoHotKey and your shortcut should work.

Comment: Thank you. But I can't install "AuotoHotKey" it gives this error:   [1]: https://file:///J:/chess.com%20series/Chess.com%20lessons/screenshots/2020-08-03%2017_58_54-Installer.ahk.pn

Comment: I don't understand it. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, it worked. you helped me a lot!